# iMessage unread count on Mac

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

I use iMessage/SMS on my Mac linked from my iPhone, I have been having issues with it on my Mac lately with the unread count being incorrect.

It says that there is a message unread when its been read on both my phone itself and my Mac. I have even deleted the conversation from my Mac but the count is still there.

It seems to be from the SMS messages I receive, I have tried enabling and disabling iMessage on Mac but that did not fix it.

(I have the latest versions of Mac OSX and iOS installed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Quit Messages
2. Open Activity Monitor, find the process called "Dock", then hit the top left "X" icon to force it the Dock process to quit. The dock should disappear and then reappear.
3. Reopen Messages. Your unread count should be reset!